# Add apk to zip Gitlab-CI? Artifacts .gitlab-ci.yml Configuration

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Following the documentation of http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html to set the file **.yml** I found the problem by creating **artifacts**, when builds the **APK** file to be downloaded this **ZIP** includes all folders: *app / build / outputs / apk* , I am interested only add the resulting **APK** to **ZIP** file to be downloaded.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
dev:
 script:
       - ./gradlew assembleDebug

 artifacts:
    name: "$CI_BUILD_NAME"
    paths:
         - app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

build.gradle file:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def apk = output.outputFile;
            def newName = "app-release-" + "myapp" + ".apk";
            output.outputFile = new File('./', newName);
        }
    }
```

.yml file:

```
dev:


script:
       - ./gradlew assembleDebug

 artifacts:
    name: "${CI_BUILD_NAME}_${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}"
    paths:
         - app/*.apk
```

*this solves the problem.*